# Allow Greater Than and Less Than in data bound columns

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

In my intranet application, I have a data bound database column that frequently contains greater than and less than characters. When the user tries to enter these values (such as "<D>"), IIS throws an "httprequestvalidationexception". Can someone tell me how I could disable this or encode the string to be safe? (Or both??)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `ValidateRequest` to `false` on your page.

Comment: Is there any other solution that this (without compromising security)?

Answer (score 0):

we have used a simple function like this in the client before posting back for anything on the server.

```
function htmlDecode(source) {
    var result = source;
   // ampersands (&)
   result = result.replace(RegExp('&amp;', 'g'), "&"); 
   // less-thans (<)
   result = result.replace(RegExp('&lt;', 'g'), "<");
   // greater-thans (>)
   result = result.replace(RegExp('&gt;', 'g'), ">");
   // Replace quotes if it isn't for display,
   result = result.replace(RegExp('&quot;', 'g'), '"');
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Is that javascript? Would I somehow bind it to my TextBox?